# Figure keeping vertically

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I have a large figure (more width than height) to place vertically (rotate the figure 90 degree anti clockways direction to the way we used to place the fig in latex) to use maximum space of the page. Please let me know How can I do.

Currently coded as

```
\begin{figure*}

\centering

{\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth]{picture/Exp.png}}

\caption{blablaa}

\label{fig:Expdiagram}

\end{figure*}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `angle=90` from `graphicx` package. Also don't use `\paperwidth`, use `\textwidth` or `\linewidth` instead. The `{}` surrounding `\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth]{picture/Exp.png}` is not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centering

\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,angle=90]{example-image-a}

\caption{blablaa}

\label{fig:Expdiagram}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to rotate the captions also, then use `rotating` package with its `sidewaysfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering

\centering

\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\caption{blablaa another figure}

\label{fig:Expdiagram1}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]